# How to include properties with default values while serializing with XMLSerializer in c#

Tags: c#, serialization, xmlserializer

By default, the `XMLSerializer` will ignore the properties with default values while performing the serialization. But I do have a special case where every property has to be serialized irrespective of the default values.

At the same time, default value attributes are serving other purposes for which I cannot remove the `DefaultValueAttribute`.

To be precise, I cannot remove the `DefaultValueAttribute` and at the same time, I want all the properties to be serialized using XML serializer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First way.

Create a data transfer object. With the same set of properties as the original class, but without the `DefaultValue` attributes.

For example you have

```
public class Person
{
    [DefaultValue(30)]
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Create

```
public class PersonDto
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Serialize like this:

```
var person = new Person { Age = 30, Name = "John" }; // original object

var personDto = new PersonDto { Age = person.Age, Name = person.Name }; // DTO

var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PersonDto));
xs.Serialize(someStream, personDto);
```

Of course, you can use automatic mapping from one object type to another. Like `AutoMapper`.

---

Second way.

Use `XmlAttributeOverrides`.

```
var person = new Person { Age = 30, Name = "John" };

var overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
var attrs = new XmlAttributes();
attrs.XmlElements.Add(new XmlElementAttribute("Age"));
overrides.Add(typeof(Person), nameof(Person.Age), attrs);

var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person), overrides);
xs.Serialize(someStream, person);
```

Now it will serialize default value.

Comment: The second approach works like a charm. Thanks a lot.